# Flexbox layout issue with rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having an issue with flexbox laying out something the way I want.

Here is what I want it to look like.
I want the text in the p tag to be on a line below the other divs. see the image for how it should look.

[Image of what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MCLY.png)

Here is a link to how I have it currently.

https://jsfiddle.net/dmmccollough/642thkoc/5/

here is the html, see the link for all the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageItem">
  <img width="90px" height="90px" src="https://i.ibb.co/9trZY0b/O-Net-Legend.png" border="0">
    </div>
    <div class="item-1 item">FF-000312</div>
    <div class="item-2 item">Last Modified: 01/09/2020</div>
    <p>Descriptive text describing the nature of the reported issue.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the content in to an other div
flexbox only styles one child level down
of cource you have to style the content a bit more

```
<div class="container">
<div class="imageItem">
  <img width="90px" height="90px" src="https://i.ibb.co/9trZY0b/O-Net-Legend.png" border="0">
    </div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="item-1 item">FF-000312</div>
    <p>Descriptive text describing the nature of the reported issue.</p>
</div>
<div class="item-2 item">Last Modified: 01/09/2020</div>
</div>
```

If you want the descriptive text to span across both you have to nest a bit and flex the header

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="imageItem">
  <img width="90px" height="90px" src="https://i.ibb.co/9trZY0b/O-Net-Legend.png" border="0">
    </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
        <div class="item-1 item">FF-000312</div> 
        <div class="item-2 item">Last Modified: 01/09/2020</div>
    </div>
    <p>Descriptive text describing the nature of the reported issue.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```